# Powershell Variable translation

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I have a following PS function:

```
function Ask-Creds {
    param(
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    $Creds = (Get-credential -message 'Please enter  Technician`s login & password for Terminal registration:')
    )
    $vault="http://1.1.1.1:8200"

    #Here I store error message in $State variable inside function:
    $rawcontent=(New-VltAuth -va $vault -AuthMethod userpass -PathData $creds.Username -AuthData @{ password = $creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password } -KeepSecretWrapper -verbose -ErrorVariable State) 

    #here I make $State variable global, to access its value outside function
    $global:State
}
```

Problem is that, when I make echo $State, I receive correct value:

```
PS C:\Users\vasyl.v> echo "$State"
400 BadRequest. {"errors":["invalid username or password"]}
```

But When I try to use this variable later:

```
if ( $state.contains("") ) { 
    echo "Technician is authenticated!"
} elseif ( $state.startswith("400 BadRequest") ) { 
    echo "Bad credentials!" | Ask-Creds 
} elseif ( $state.startswith("An error occurred while") ) { 
    echo "Connection failed!" | exit 1
}
```

I receive:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord] does not contain a method named 'contains'.
At line:1 char:6
+ if ( $state.contains("") ) {
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Anyone can hint me, how to get rid of "[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]" and receive value as in an echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.contains()` method you are looking for belongs to class String. Your $state variable references a **System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord** object. I see a few options for you, and you only need to do one of them:

1. Use other logic besides `.contains()`. You could switch to using the `-contains` or `-in` operator. Regex could be used for the logic where you need to find starting strings.
2. Change $state to be a string before doing your comparisons. You could run `$global:State = -join $state` in your function if the output is not an array. This could also be done if your object has a `toString()` method by running `$global:State = $state.toString()`.

Comment: I did check and System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord supports toString() method.